# Stored Procedure Return Value Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've written this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertUpdate_Customer]
(    
     @cfname varchar(200),
     @clname varchar(200),
     @address1 varchar(200),
     @address2 varchar(200),
     @city varchar(200),
     @pincode varchar(50),
     @mobileno varchar(20),
     @brno int,
     @birthdate datetime,
     @age int,
     @gender char,
     @email varchar(50),
     @bal float,
     @acctype varchar(200),
     @opendate date,
     @flag int,
     @vchrMsg varchar(200) output
)
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction t1    
    begin try


        declare @dt varchar(200)
        declare @no varchar(200)
        declare @cust_id varchar(200)
        declare @accno varchar(200)

        set @dt= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 126))


        if(@flag=1) 
        BEGIN

            SET @dt= CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), GETDATE(), 126);
            exec @dt= dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters @dt;
            select @cust_id = CONCAT((LEFT(@cfname,1)),(LEFT(@clname,1))) 
            SET @no= CONCAT(@cust_id,@dt);
            SELECT CAST(@brno as varchar(200))
            SET @accno='123'

            insert into tbl_customer(cust_id, cust_fname, cust_lname, cust_bdate, cust_age, cust_address1, cust_address2, cust_city, cust_zipcode, cust_gen, cust_contactno, cust_brno, cust_accno, cust_balance, cust_acctype, cust_opendate, IsActive)
            values(@no, @cfname, @clname, @birthdate, @age, @address1, @address2, @city, @pincode, @gender, @mobileno, @brno, @accno, @bal, @acctype, @opendate, 'Y')

            set @vchrMsg=@cust_id----successfully inserted
        END
    end try
    begin catch
        set @vchrMsg=ERROR_MESSAGE()
        PRINT @vchrMsg
        rollback transaction t1
        return
    end catch
    commit transaction t1
END

select Msg = @vchrMsg;
return @vchrMsg;
Print @vchrMsg
```

Now when I tried to execute this statement:

```
exec SP_InsertUpdate_Customer 'Anup'
                             ,'Patil'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'07029'
                             ,'000000000'
                             ,123
                             ,'03/02/1989'
                             ,25
                             ,'M'
                             ,'anuppatil007@gmail.com'
                             ,200
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'07/16/2015'
                             ,1,''
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_InsertUpdate_Customer, Line 90
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AP' to data
>   type int.

Please help me to sort it out..

Comment: In which column is stored 'AP' value?

Comment: dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters check this store procedure or function

Comment: provide code of `dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters`

Comment: well it hase lot of "@" signs for variables.. dont know but this editor doesn;t allow me to insert code here.. but that code doesn't matter.. you can ignore it...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Stored procedure's return value can **only** be an `INT` - usually used to indicate the number of rows affected by the stored procedure, or to indicate an error condition. You **cannot** return a `varchar` message from a stored procedure using `RETURN` - you need to use the `OUTPUT` parameter, or a `SELECT` result set instead

Answer (score 2):

Remove last three lines from the sproc definition as that's not required:

```
--select Msg = @vchrMsg;
--return @vchrMsg;
--Print @vchrMsg
```

and execute sp as:

```
declare @vchrMsg varchar(200)
exec SP_InsertUpdate_Customer 'Anup'
                             ,'Patil'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'07029'
                             ,'000000000'
                             ,123
                             ,'03/02/1989'
                             ,25
                             ,'M'
                             ,'anuppatil007@gmail.com'
                             ,200
                             ,'demo'
                             ,'07/16/2015'
                             ,1,@vchrMsg out
select @vchrMsg
```

Moreover keep in mind `OUTPUT` and `RETURN` keywords have different purpose.The [Return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) value is always an `INT`.

EDIT:
<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TPFQ72042)</kbd>

Comment: I tried that.. Now error gone.. But record didnt inserted... It says 1 row affected but record didnt exist in table,,

Comment: That shouldn't be the case..Check the demo .. it's working fine over thr.. let me know where the actual conditions differ..

Comment: Ok.. It displays custId.. but still record is not inserted in table.. I tried exact code in my sql query editor..

Comment: Yaa.. got error.. I've created trigger Instead Insert on same table.. If I disable this trigger then values are inserted.. But Even I want trigger to work.. How can I do it? T

Answer (score 1):

Use

`SELECT  @vchrMsg  AS Message;`

Instead of

```
  return @vchrMsg;
```

return type of Stored Procedure is always `Int` (returns the no of rows affected or Error code in case of Error).